# Pandas Bar Chart Issue

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a small dataframe, which looks like this:

```
In [639]: x
Out[639]:
    Local    State
1   3.2      6.2
2   5.3      10.4
3   14.9     29.17
4   8.5      16.6
5   6.95     13.5
6   12.3     23.9
```

I use the following code to create a bar chart, and try to tweak it. The problem is, instead of tweaking the produced bar chart, the code creates an empty plot, and underneath, there is the Pandas bar chart. It is hard to describe, so I have attached a picture. Any ideas?

EDIT: Instead of trying to plot the 2 column dataframe, if I select and try to plot a single column (e.g. `x.['col1'].plot(kind='bar')`, then the code works fine. This is confusing...

Thanks!

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6), dpi = 72)
plt.xlabel('RF Region')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [%]')
plt.title('Distribution of Rating Results')
ylim(0,50)

x.plot(kind='bar',color=colors,alpha=0.75)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', linewidth=1.0)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you created a figure with an axis, and then you use pandas `plot` which does that again, and you end up with two figures. You should instead pass the (already created) `axis` object  to the `plot` function. This way pandas will plot on that particular `axis` instead of creating a new one. Example:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6), dpi = 72)
plt.xlabel('RF Region')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [%]')
plt.title('Distribution of Rating Results')
ylim(0,50)
ax = plt.gca()
colors= ['r', 'b']
df.plot(kind='bar',color=colors, alpha=0.75, ax=ax)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(5))
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', linewidth=1.0)
plt.grid(b=True, which='minor')
```

Comment: thanks, it worked like a charm! I still do not get why it works if use the code above, but try to plot a single column from the dataframe. It just creates a single plot then, instead of two...

Comment: @marillion The Series plot function uses the current figure and axes (gcf, gca) and the DataFrame plot, since it has to do more things, creates it's own figure.